# Cache Proxy Server in Python

Tags: python, caching, networking, tcp, proxy

I have a homework assignment which involves implementing a proxy cache server in Python. The idea is to write the web pages I access to temporary files on my local machine and then access them as requests come in if they are stored. Right now the code looks like this:

```
from socket import *
import sys

def main():
    #Create a server socket, bind it to a port and start listening
    tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) #Initializing socket
    tcpSerSock.bind(("", 8030)) #Binding socket to port
    tcpSerSock.listen(5) #Listening for page requests
    while True:
        #Start receiving data from the client
        print 'Ready to serve...'
        tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
        print 'Received a connection from:', addr
        message = tcpCliSock.recv(1024)
        print message

        #Extract the filename from the given message
        print message.split()[1]
        filename = message.split()[1].partition("/")[2]
        print filename
        fileExist = "false"
        filetouse = "/" + filename
        print filetouse

        try: #Check whether the file exists in the cache
            f = open(filetouse[1:], "r")
            outputdata = f.readlines()
            fileExist = "true"
            #ProxyServer finds a cache hit and generates a response message
            tcpCliSock.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n")
            tcpCliSock.send("Content-Type:text/html\r\n")
            for data in outputdata:
                tcpCliSock.send(data)
            print 'Read from cache'
        except IOError: #Error handling for file not found in cache
            if fileExist == "false":

                c = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) #Create a socket on the proxyserver
                hostn = filename.replace("www.","",1) 
                print hostn
                try:
                    c.connect((hostn, 80)) #https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html
                    # Create a temporary file on this socket and ask port 80 for
                    # the file requested by the client
                    fileobj = c.makefile('r', 0)
                    fileobj.write("GET " + "http://" + filename + "HTTP/1.0\r\n")
                    # Read the response into buffer
                    buffr = fileobj.readlines()
                    # Create a new file in the cache for the requested file.
                    # Also send the response in the buffer to client socket and the
                    # corresponding file in the cache
                    tmpFile = open(filename,"wb")
                    for data in buffr:
                        tmpFile.write(data)
                        tcpCliSock.send(data)
                except:
                    print "Illegal request"
            else: #File not found
                print "404: File Not Found"
        tcpCliSock.close() #Close the client and the server sockets

main()
```

To test my code, I run the proxy cache on my localhost and set my browser proxy settings accordingly like so

[image]

However, when I run this code and try to access google with Chrome, I'm greeting with an error page saying err_empty_response.

Stepping through the code with the debugger made me realizing it's failing on this line

```
c.connect((hostn, 80))
```

and I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm testing this with Google Chrome, Python 2.7, and Windows 10

Comment: Cutting off the `www.` is dangerous. Neither does the name without the `www.` have to resolve nor does it have to resolve to the same IP address as the one with the `www.`.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Unfortunately, removing the part where I cut that out doesn't fix the issue

Comment: No. See my answer. You need to resolve the name first. Check the [documentation for `getaddrinfo()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a name on connect. Connect expects an IP address to connect to.

You can get the socket information you need to build the connection using [`getaddrinfo()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo). In my [`pure-python-whois`](https://github.com/jsfan/pure-python-whois/blob/master/ppwhois/whois.py#L288) package I used the following code to create a connection:

```
def _openconn(self, server, timeout, port=None):
    port = port if port else 'nicname'
    try:
        for srv in socket.getaddrinfo(server, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_ADDRCONFIG):
            af, socktype, proto, _, sa = srv
            try:
                c = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
            except socket.error:
                c = None
                continue
            try:
                if self.source_addr:
                    c.bind(self.source_addr)
                c.settimeout(timeout)
                c.connect(sa)
            except socket.error:
                c.close()
                c = None
                continue
            break
    except socket.gaierror:
        return False

    return c
```

Note that this isn't great code because the loop is actually there for nothing instead of using the different alternatives. You should only break the loop once you have established a connection. However, this should work as an illustration for using `getaddrinfo()`

EDIT:
You are also not cleaning your hostname correctly. I get `/www.example.com/` when I try accessing `http://www.example.com/` which obviously won't resolve. I'd suggest that you use a regular expression to get the file name for your cache.

Comment: Changing the line to srv = c.getaddrinfo(filename, 80) then c.connect((srv, 80)) throws an error saying socket object has no attribute getaddrinfo

Comment: You still have to ensure that filename is actually the hostname. You can't have the path in the hostname when you resolve it. It has to be just a hostname nothing else.

Comment: I just tested it by calling c.getaddrinfo(("www.google.com", 80)) and got the same error. _socketobject object has no attribute getaddrinfo

Comment: That's not how it is in my code above. `c` should not even exist yet at the time you call `getaddrinfo()`. Have a look at my code sample again.

Comment: I realized what happened. since I import socket by saying from socket import * and getaddrinfo is static I just call getaddrinfo not c.getaddrinfo

Comment: Cache server still isn't working like I expect it to but im gonna post a separate question, accepting this answer since it solved this question's problem. Thanks!

Comment: It would be `socket.getaddrinfo()` otherwise, never a method of the socket. ;)